# Power BI desktop - new column refreshes data

Tags: powerbi, desktop, calculated-columns

I hope you can help here.

I'm trying to create a new column on the Data screen on PowerBI Desktop.

I click **[New column]** and it adds a column "Column" - however when I try to rename it I get a data refresh message (see attached screenshot) and the column doesn't get added.

This happens as soon as I click into the 'Name' field or right click on the column in the 'Fields' panel.

This seems a peculiar feature.  Otherwise I'm guessing it's a bug.

I've reinstalled the PowerBI desktop app however get the same results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yszdy.png)

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Where from you are adding that "New Column"? May be a screen shoot will help to understand it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some text or anything while creating column. Otherwise when you click on any other place it will automatically removed.

e.g. Column = "Test"

After adding above code try to rename.